# How can I prevent panel.function from overriding my settings?

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to write a text on a barchart while using my own color settings. I could manage to update the settings and write a text on the panel separately but I could not find a way to combine the two. As far as I understand, panel.function overrides some of my previous colour settings. How can I prevent "panel.function" from overriding my preferences?

For example:

```
#This is to extract data and colour options

library(RColorBrewer)
library(lattice)
data(postdoc, package = "latticeExtra")

#This is how I set my preferences

myColours <- brewer.pal(6,"Greys")
my.settings13 <- list(
  superpose.polygon=list(col=myColours[2:5], border="transparent"),
  strip.border=list(col="black")
)

#The first plot has the right settings but no text.
#The second has the text but the legend goes back to its default settings.    

print(plot1<-barchart(prop.table(postdoc,margin=1), horizontal=F, ylab = "Proportion", auto.key = list(adj = 1,column=4),par.settings=my.settings13,ltext=list(1, 0.8,"0.5" ) ))

print(plot2<-barchart(prop.table(postdoc,margin=1), horizontal=F, ylab = "Proportion", auto.key = list(adj = 1,column=4),par.settings=my.settings13,panel=function(x,y,...){
  panel.barchart(x,y,...)
  panel.text(1,0.80,labels=c("0.5"))
  panel.text(2,0.50,labels=c("0.75"))
}))
```

How can I write a text (as in plot2) but keep all my colour settings (as in plot 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this, you need to slightly customize the `auto.key` values. If the panel is the string `"panel.barchart"` this is done automatically, but if you change the panel at all, this automatic conversion is disabled. Specifically, set `points=FALSE`, and `rectangles=TRUE`. This should work.

```
print(plot2<-barchart(prop.table(postdoc,margin=1), 
    horizontal=F, ylab = "Proportion", 
    auto.key = list(adj = 1,column=4, points=FALSE, rectangles=TRUE),
    par.settings=my.settings13, panel=function(x,y,...){
  panel.barchart(x,y,...)
  panel.text(1,0.80,labels=c("0.5"))
  panel.text(2,0.50,labels=c("0.75"))
}))
```

If you want to see where this happens, it's actually in the `lattice:::bwplot.formula` function (which is the function that actually does all the work for bar plots) and is has to do with the `is.standard.barchart` variable.